# Hide the bottom image view when showing keyboard react-native

Tags: react-native, view, keyboard, react-native-textinput

[image: I have form Login with two textInput]

[image: And when keyboard showing...]

How I can hide this picture...
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Keyboard](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard) in ReactNative to listen for changes of keyboard and hide your image when the keyboard is visible.

check below sample code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Keyboard, TextInput, Image } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isKeyboadVisible: false,
    text: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      isKeyboadVisible: true
    });
  };

  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    this.setState({
      isKeyboadVisible: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: "80%",
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginBottom: 10
          }}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        {!this.state.isKeyboadVisible && (
          <Image
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
            source={{ uri: "https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png" }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Change the above code according to your requirements.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to using ScrollView to wrapper your view. Therefore, when you click to input component, keyboard will overlap your picture.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-scrollview#__docusaurus

Another solution is try to using KeyboardAvoidingView
https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview